# React app anchor tags not working on netlify

Tags: reactjs, anchor, netlify

it is my first ever Netlify app https://muarif-quran.netlify.app/

I am facing an issue in the footer section and all over the website my anchor tags not working…

for example I added clients Facebook page link but whenever I try to click on it its not redirecting me.

however its working fine on local host.

can anyone help me please

can any one help me please?

the code is here!

```
<div id="share">
        <i className="fas fa-share"></i>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_OFFICIAL}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-facebook"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_TELEGRAM}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-telegram"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_WHATSAPP_ONE}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-whatsapp"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={"http://meet.google.com/twv-pkwa-efv"}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-google"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_YOUTUBE_OFFICIAL}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-youtube"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_PERSONAL}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-facebook-f"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_PHONE}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fas fa-phone"
        ></a>
        <a
          href={process.env.REACT_APP_WHATSAPP_PERSONAL}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          className="fab fa-whatsapp"
        ></a>
      </div>
```

`your text`

Comment: Did you set .env in your netlify account? I hope this [Netlify Env Doc](https://docs.netlify.com/environment-variables/overview/) help you

Comment: but If you see my code there is also ink which is not rendering from .env

Comment: Are you sure your code is deployed correctly? Maybe it didn't update your code and that's why you don't have the link up there
another thing is if you want to use a string value you don't need to use brackets.

Comment: Yes there was my one bug that my string value was wrapped in curly braces..

Comment: But the actual problem is still existing I don't know why its happening that my environment variable working fine on localhost but on netlify its not working so the problem is in netlify environment variables... Do you have any solution or any YouTube video link please?

Comment: I really don't know. I didn't work that much with netlify but it's obvious that the problem is with setting the env variables. I think there are videos that you can use to see how to set it. the link I sent in my first comment is related to the matter. check and see if it helps or not.

Comment: Yes thanks bro its was the problem about setting env variable

Comment: Heroku stop is free services.. now which one is better for backend?

Comment: Can i host Express and mongoDb in netlify too?

Comment: Hi @SafarAbbas how can you fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I fix this issue by adding white space in anchor tag